# Android Task<FirebaseVisionText> not returning FirebaseVisionText type

Tags: java, android, android-task, firebase-machine-learning

I'm trying to pull the text and blocks from my image processed through a FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer, and even though the processing is successful, it doesn't seem to return as the correct type.  Android studio reports that result is of type Task<FirebaseVisionText> instead of type FirebaseVisionText, as the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/recognize-text#java_9) suggests it should.

Here is the problem area:
'''FirebaseVisionImage fImg = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(curBitmap);
FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer tscan = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getOnDeviceTextRecognizer();
System.out.println("before task");

```
    Task<FirebaseVisionText> result =
            tscan.processImage(fImg)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseVisionText>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(FirebaseVisionText firebaseVisionText) {
                            System.out.println("task success");
                            // Task completed successfully
                            // ...
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(
                            new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    System.out.println("task fail");
                                    // Task failed with an exception
                                    // ...
                                }
                            });
    String str = result.getText();'''
```

The line:
`String str = result.getText();`
reports the error: Cannot resolve method 'getText' in 'Task'

I tried casting result to FirebaseVisionText as well as setting a new FirebaseVisionText equal to result, but neither solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by replacing `String str = result.getText();` with `Tasks.await(result); return result.getResult();` and calling the containing function on a new thread: `new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() { try{ containingFunction();} catch {}}}).start();`